# Cypress email testing with virtual smtp server (mailtrap)

Tags: testing, smtp, cypress, mailtrap

My goal is to use mailtrap as a virtual SMTP server and use Cypress to be able to (through mailtraps interface) visualize how the emails look and test their contents to catch any inconsistencies.

I found a package called "cypress-mailtrap", but it looks like an abandoned project with no instructions: https://github.com/xedi/cypress-mailtrap.

Has anyone set up anything like this before or have any tips on how to approach it?

Comment: If you look at the plugins page of cypress docs, there are few email plugins one can use to test emails. Have you considered any of these? https://docs.cypress.io/plugins#Email

Answer (score 0):

I also tried installing cypress-mailtrap, but faced different issues. So I switched to an open-source option, mailhog and it worked successfully.

Comment: A link to this mailhog package would be useful...